# AJAX Webworker Polling with setTimeout

Tags: javascript, ajax, settimeout, web-worker, polling

I'm trying to get a webworker to poll a web server interface on the same machine every second or so. Most articles I have read say to avoid setInterval and use setTimeout instead but I have yet to find an example that uses AJAX instead of Jquery.

The code I have so far is below:

```
(function poll() {
    setTimeout(function() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function() {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
            responseObject = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            var newContent = '';
            newContent += responseObject.cmd;
            console.log(newContent);
        }
    }
    xhr.open('GET', 'http://localhost:8194/screen_update/1000', true);
    xhr.send(null);
    setTimeout(poll, 1000);
}, 1000);
})();
```

The preferred output would be to poll the server each second which should in theory be more than adequate for the response to come through. I only want one request on the go at a time so if I end up with a request taking more than a second it just dumps the request (rather than queuing it) and issues a new request.

The above code polls okay but doesn't complete for 2 seconds so I've obviously got my setTimeout mixed up somewhere. Where do I correct this code?

Comment: put the timeout in the onoad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a variable that determines if ajax finished or not. If function is called while ajax hasn't finished yet, you can exit the function and wait for the next call.

```
var stillWorking = false;

(function poll() {
   if(stillWorking) return false; 
   stillWorking = true;
    setTimeout(function() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) stillWorking = false;
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
            responseObject = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            var newContent = '';
            newContent += responseObject.cmd;
            console.log(newContent);

        }
    }
    xhr.open('GET', 'http://localhost:8194/screen_update/1000', true);
    xhr.send(null);
    setTimeout(poll, 1000);
}, 1000);
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

I did just that a few days ago.. and while it may not be the most elegant, it works fine so far.
I have the worker handle the timeout / check interval, not the main JS. So I guess that's one more thing that the UI doesn't need to handle. Here is my worker code:

```
function checkStatus() {    
    console.log("statusCheck started");

    var ajaxRequest;
    try { ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest(); // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
    } catch (e) { try { // Internet Explorer Browsers
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) { try {
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) { // Something went wrong
                console.error("AJAX not possible");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }


    // Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4) {

            self.postMessage(ajaxRequest.responseText);

            var timer;
            timer = self.setTimeout(function(){
                checkStatus();
            }, 1000);

        }
    }

    ajaxRequest.open("GET", "/worker_statusCheck.php", true);
    ajaxRequest.send(null);

}



this.onmessage  =   function(e){
    checkStatus(); // the message comes in just once on pageLoad
};
```

Comment: BTW: this DOESN'T check every second. This checks again one second AFTER successfull AJAX response.

Answer (score 0):

You can call same function when you get response of AJAX. In this way no need to check that currently AJAX is in process or not.

```
function poll() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange= function() {

        if (xhr.status === 200) {
            responseObject = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            var newContent = '';
            newContent += responseObject.cmd;
            console.log(newContent);

        }
        if (xhr.readyState == 4)
        {
            setTimeout(function(){ poll();},1000);
        }
    }
    xhr.open('GET', 'http://localhost:8194/screen_update/1000', true);
    xhr.send(null);
};
setTimeout(function(){ poll();},1000);
```

If you want to use onload callback then callback code should be

```
 xhr.onload= function() {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
            responseObject = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            var newContent = '';
            newContent += responseObject.cmd;
            console.log(newContent);

        }
        setTimeout(function(){ poll();},1000);
    }
```

Comment: this will stop ajax requests if status code is not 200

Comment: ohh, yes... we have to check ajax state if state is 4 .

Comment: Is there any reason you changed to onreadystatechange from onload that you had in your first draft? I got the first draft working fine, can I still just use the xhr.readyState with xhr.onload?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using `HTML5 WebWorker`, probably, you can use `window.fetch` which uses promises (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), I think that browser support is almost the same.

Here is an example:

```js
((url, INTERVAL, configs) => {
  const MAX_ERRORS = 4;
  let errors = 0;
  var poll = () => window.setTimeout(getData, INTERVAL);
  
  function getData() {
    return window
      .fetch(url, configs)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        errors = 0;
        poll();    
        return data;
      })
      .then((data) => {
        console.log("new data available", data);
      })
      .catch(() => {
        if(errors >= MAX_ERRORS) {
          console.log("GIVING UP");
          return;
        }
        
        errors += 1;
        return poll();
      })
    ;
  }
 
  
  return poll();
})("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1", 1000, {
  method: 'GET' 
});
```